# GPS location providers which does not use google play services

Tags: android, gps, location-provider

I have an android device that have a GPS chip on it and I want to get location using it, but the device doesn't have google play service installed (it doesn't support google play service). So I'm not able to use android standard `LocationManager`.

Does anyone have suggestions how to get location?

Comment: i dont think so LocationManager has anything to do with google play service. its in android package

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira: I tested it. Location listener won't work if google play service is not installed !!

Comment: what do you mean *"wont work"*?show me your logcat

Comment: It never goes inside on 'onLocationChanged' method. I tested the application on my mobile handset, and it works fine. I'm completely sure about it. I'm looking for other GPS location providers.

Comment: As i did not believe your statement i did a test with two devices where i first stopped Google play services. They fixed.

Comment: if you want simulate my device stopping google play service is not enough, you should stop **location** services in google service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`LocationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) which does not require Google Play Services and gives you direct access to GPS, network, and/or passive location updates.

You are likely trying to use the newer [Location API](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) which require Google Play Services. The newer API, which replaces the `LocationManager` with the `FusedProvider` automatically switches between passive, network and GPS based on user settings and location. While this is simpler to implement and likely more battery efficient, you should be completely fine using the older `LocationManager`.